# SeekBar and CountDownTimer

Tags: android, reset, seekbar, countdowntimer

i'm trying to use a SeekBar to control the speed of the CountDownTimer and i'm stopped in 2 issues.
1 - The DownTimerInterval doesn't reset when i change the seekbar progress...but add the progress value every time i change.
2 - I want to stop the countdown when the seekbar progress is set to 0....and it don't work.
How to fix that?

Here is my code

```
rolagem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        rolagemAutomatica();
    }
});

private void rolagemAutomatica() {
    barra = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.exibir_musica.barraFonte);
    barra.setVisibility(1);
    barra.setMax(4);
    barra.setProgress(0);
    barra.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            String[] VR = {"0","10","50","75","100"};
            //Define crono +1 cause position 0 crash the app
            int crono = Integer.parseInt(VR[progress]+1);

            CountDownTimer test = new CountDownTimer(400000 , crono) {

                @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        scroll_letra.smoothScrollBy(0,
                                (int) (millisUntilFinished / 300000));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                };
                if(crono-1 != 0){
                    test.start();
                }else{
                    test.cancel();
                }
            }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold the CountDownTimer as an instance field so that you can cancel it when you need to.  If starting one with a tick timer of 0 crashes you, then just don't start one when the speed is 0.

Something like this:

```
barra.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        String[] VR = {"0","10","50","75","100"};
        int crono = Integer.parseInt(VR[progress]);

        if (fromUser) {
            this.countDownTimer.cancel();
            if (crono > 0) {
                 this.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(400000 , crono) {

                     @Override
                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                         scroll_letra.smoothScrollBy(0,
                                 (int) (millisUntilFinished / 300000));

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onFinish() {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         }
                     };
                     if(crono-1 != 0){
                         test.start();
                     }else{
                         test.cancel();
                     }
                }
            }
        }
});
```

There are some more optimizations you could do. For example, you could probably define VR as just an array of ints so you don't have to parse them, and you could keep them on the instance so you don't have to create the array over and over, etc.:

```
 int[] VR = new int[] {0, 10, 50, 75, 100};
```

Comment: hi Dokkaebi...sorry to reply later...many things to focus in the project...and this is the last one...finally. This solution don't work for me...the countDown doesn't cancel. I'm looking after this and looking for another way to make it...so..ty for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue.

i declare the countDownTimer as a global variable.

```
CountDownTimer ctimer = null;
```

after that...i create a method

```
private void timerRol(int contador) {
    if (contador == 0){
        Log.v(String.valueOf(contador), "Stopped");
    }else{  
        ctimer = new CountDownTimer(400000, contador) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            scroll_letra.smoothScrollBy(0, (int) (millisUntilFinished / 300000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
    ctimer.start();
    }
}
```

after created the method...i call it on OnCreate passing a value as parameter...and stop it after the call.

```
timerRol(100);
ctimer.cancel();
```

after that i create the seekbar and call the method when the user change the position.

```
barraRolagem = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.exibir_musica.barraRolagem);
    barraRolagem.setVisibility(1);
    barraRolagem.setMax(5);
    barraRolagem.setProgress(0);
    final int[] crono = { 0, 750, 500, 100, 50, 1};

    barraRolagem.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    if((crono[progress] == 0)) {

                            ctimer.cancel();
                    }else{

                        Log.v(String.valueOf(crono[progress]), "valor do crono");
                        ctimer.cancel();
                        timerRol(crono[progress]);

                    }
                }
            });
```